# Why are adresses not showing up in gettxout?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

I have a bitcoin node but whenever i try to gettxout i get this response:

```
user@bitcoin:~# bitcoin-cli gettxout "0e3e2357e806b6cdb1f70b54c3a3a17b6714ee1f0e68bebb44a74b1efd512098" 0 
{ "bestblock": "0000000000000000007c11ddb3e10be41ef0f6a2a5dbc2915937df8a608c4af6",   "confirmations": 385308,   "value": 50.00000000,   "scriptPubKey": {
    "asm": "0496b538e853519c726a2c91e61ec11600ae1390813a627c66fb8be7947be63c52da7589379515d4e0a604f8141781e62294721166bf621e73a82cbf2342c858ee OP_CHECKSIG",
    "hex": "410496b538e853519c726a2c91e61ec11600ae1390813a627c66fb8be7947be63c52da7589379515d4e0a604f8141781e62294721166bf621e73a82cbf2342c858eeac",
    "type": "pubkey"   },   "coinbase": true } 
user@bitcoin:~# bitcoin-cli gettxout "0e3e2357e806b6cdb1f70b54c3a3a17b6714ee1f0e68bebb44a74b1efd512098" 1
```

I have txindex=1 in my config file and it's reindexed. Anything else i can try?

Answer (score 3):

Not every transaction output has an address. In this case, the output you are looking at, while it is a standard output type, it does not have an associated address. It is a Pay to Public Key script for which there is no address. Thus `gettxout` does not provide an address.